# Can CASL.js evaluate field restrictions directly against a subject?

Tags: casl

#### Description

My objective is to evaluate a `req.body` as a **CASL.js** `subject` (built with the built-in [subject helper](https://casl.js.org/v5/en/api/casl-ability#subject)) and to determine not only if the user can perform an action against that subject under the predefined `conditions`, but also if the provided `req.body` has **only** the permitted `fields` defined in the `AbilityTuple` used for the `Ability` constructor.

I was almost sure that this was the predetermined functionality of the `can()` utility until I ran with an unorthodox use of it (not important in this context), where it was obvious that, as long as the `conditions` matched, the subject evaluated could hold any other fields different than the ones defined in the `fields` array.

#### Illustrative example

I have a user 'grant' (a permission) defined in a database JSON:

```
{
  "action": "create",
  "subject": "users",
  "conditions": {
    "idPlatform": 8,
    "idRole": 14
  },
  "fields": [
    "idPlatform",
    "idRole",
    "attributes.**",
    "key",
    "person.documents.**",
    "person.emails.**
  ]
}
```

This is passed to the `new Ability()` constructor along with all the other permissions of a given user, fetched from database. Then an endpoint controller evaluates a user authorization for performing a *user creation* action before moving on to further methods, using the `ability.can()` utility in the following way:

```
async authorize(req) {
  const userSubject = subject('users', req.body);
  if (!await this.ability.can('create', userSubject)) {
    throw new Error('Unauthorized');
  }
}
```

Now suppose a user sends the following body to this endpoint:

```
idPlatform: 8,
idRole: 14,
key: "myusername",
active: 0,
person: {
  documents: [
    {
      idType: 1,
      document: "37548323"
    },
    {
      idType: 3,
      document: "20375483231"
    },
  emails: [
    {
      idType: 2,
      email: "mypersonalemail@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      idType: 3,
      email: "myworkemail"
    }
  ],
  telephones: [
    {
      "idType": 1
      "telephone": "29445368432"
  ]
}
```

As you may see, there are two additional fields apart from those declared in the `fields` ability object: `active` and `person.telephones`. But since the body matches the two conditions defined (`idPlatform` and `idRole`), the `ability.can()` method returns **true**.

What I'd like is that the `ability.can()` utility would also evaluate if the provided subject has **only** the fields allowed for the user, or return **false** if there are any extra fields. Currently I can achieve that by flattening the subject keys into an strings array:

```
['idPlatform', 'idRole', 'key', 'active', 'person.documents.idType', 'person.documents.document', ...]
```

...and iterating through them with the `ability.can('create', subject, flattenedField)`.

Comment: Read this: https://casl.js.org/v6/en/api/casl-ability-extra#permitted-fields-of

Comment: Thanks @SergiiStotskyi! I was aware of that function and it's utility, and it will probably be part of my custom solution.